# Form control within Groupbox control

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have multiple form application in vb.net
Now i rose to a condition where i want to display one Form in the Groupbox/Panel control of other form.
Is there any way to achieve that???
Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

If you must, you can do that.  Here is an example:

```
Dim f As New Form
f.TopLevel = False
f.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
f.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
f.Visible = True
Panel1.Controls.Add(f)
```

The `TopLevel = False` is a requirement.  Setting the FormBorderStyle and Dock style are optional, but probably what you are looking to do.

Comment: Now i have to explore my condition, i have one tab strip control having two tabs.
On one tab i have Panel control where i have showed another form and this other form have one button "Submit".
On other tab i have some controls and one button "OK".
Now on clicking "OK" button i have to call the click event of "Submit" button of the form on panel on other tab..

So how can i achieve that?? Any help is appriciated...

Comment: @Vijay I can't see your code from here, but you are asking a different question.  Stack Overflow is for one question at a time.  That being said, their are a lot of examples to do what you are asking here.  The simple thing is to have a reference to your form that contains the submit button, and just call it directly, example: `f.submitButton_Click(nothing, nothing)`.

Comment: thanks Lars.. i got solution with addhandler. Thank you for ur concern. it means lot to me..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put Form on another Form - use User Control for that.

see

[User Control vs. Windows Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299339/user-control-vs-windows-form)

Comment: I always do that, it is not a problem to put a form on another form, but you need to set `f.TopLevel = False`