# How to set selectedValue to Controls.Combobox in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, controls

I have a combobox and I see that I am not able to set SelectedValue like this:

```
cmbA.SelectedValue = "asd"
```

So I tried to do this

```
cmbA.SelectedIndex = cmbA.FindString("asd");
```

Based on [How to set selected value from Combobox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688157/how-to-set-selected-value-from-combobox)

I realised that my combobox is a System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox and not a System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.

That means that FindString() is not available.

Based on [User Control vs. Windows Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299339/user-control-vs-windows-form) I get that forms are the container for controls, but I dont get why the Controls.ComboBox does not implement FindString().

Do I have to write my own code to do what FindString() does for Forms.ComboBox?

Comment: @siwmas `SelectedValue` will not be set only if there is no such value in `ComboBox` (the same goes for `SelectedItem` and `SelectedIndex`), so check once more whether your `ComboBox` actually contains `"asd"` string as one of its values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF ComboBoxes are not the same as WinForms ones. They can display a collection of objects, instead of just strings.

Lets say for example if I had

```
myComboBox.ItemsSource = new List<string> { "One", "Two", "Three" };
```

I could just use the following line of code to set the `SelectedItem`

```
myComboBox.SelectedItem = "Two";
```

We're not limited to just strings here. I could also say I want to bind my ComboBox to a `List<MyCustomClass>`, and I want to set the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` to a `MyCustomClass` object.

For example,

```
List<MyCustomClass> data = new List<MyCustomClass> 
{ 
    new MyCustomClass() { Id = 1, Name = "One" },
    new MyCustomClass() { Id = 2, Name = "Two" },
    new MyCustomClass() { Id = 3, Name = "Three" }
};
myComboBox.ItemsSource = data;
myComboBox.SelectedItem = data[0];
```

I could also tell WPF I want to consider the `Id` property on `MyCustomClass` to be the identifying property, and I want to set `MyCombbox.SelectedValue = 2`, and it will know to find the `MyCustomClass` object with the `.Id` property of 2, and set it as selected.

```
myComboBox.SelectedValuePath = "Id";
myComboBox.SelectedValue = 2;
```

I could even set the Display Text to use a different property using

```
myComboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
```

To summarize, WPF ComboBoxes work with more than just Strings, and because of the expanded capabilities, FindString is not needed. What you are most likely looking for is to set the `SelectedItem` to one of the objects that exist in your `ItemsSource` collection.

And if you're not using ItemsSource, then a standard for-each loop should work too

```
foreach(ComboBoxItem item in myComboBox.Items)
{
    if (item.Content == valueToFind)
        myComboBox.SelectedItem = item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know  what you are trying to do but I think it would be easier to just do

`cmbA.Text = "String";`

That way you get your selected item

Else I found an intersting article that could help you out:
[Difference between SelectedItem, SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902039/difference-between-selecteditem-selectedvalue-and-selectedvaluepath)